# Exponential absolute positioning axis value

Tags: javascript

I try to make a div move down with an exponential speed. My problem is that the speed value used in my function seems to be not working.

I'm a beginner in javascript and I suppose that I did'nt place the incrementation at the right place.

```
<title>test2</title>
<style type="text/css">
#ball {
    -webkit-border-radius: 100%;
    -moz-border-radius: 100%;
    border-radius: 100%;
    background:red;
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    position:absolute;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>

<div id="container">

    <div id="ball" style="top:200px;left:200px;"></div>

    <script>
        var speed=0;
        function bounce(speed) {
            speed++;
            var ball = document.getElementById("ball");
            var topValue = parseInt(ball.style.top, 10);
            ball.style.top = (topValue + speed) + "px";
            if (topValue >= 300) {
                clearInterval(interval);
            }
        }
        var interval = setInterval(function() {bounce(speed)}, 10);

    </script>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using closures incorrectly. `speed` is not changing, because you are using it as function parameter and it is a base type `Number`. Try next:

```
    var speed=0;
    function bounce() {
        speed++;
        var ball = document.getElementById("ball");
        var topValue = parseInt(ball.style.top, 10);
        ball.style.top = (topValue + speed) + "px";
        if (topValue >= 300) {
            clearInterval(interval);
        }
    }
    var interval = setInterval(function() {bounce()}, 10);
```

Last line can be replaced with: `var interval = setInterval(bounce, 10);`